# Unable to get first element in a table on 0 position while retrieving it?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is my jsp page

```
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
    <%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
    <%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <% 
    SessionFactory sessionfactory=null;
    Session Listsession=null ;
    sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
     Listsession = sessionfactory.openSession();
          String name="";
          String age="";
          String address="";
          String phone_no="";
      try
    {
      int c=0;
     if(request.getAttribute("c")!=null)
    {

      c=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("c").toString());
       }

        org.hibernate.Query query=Listsession.createQuery("select name,age,address,phone_number from paging order by auto_inc"); 
       query.setFirstResult(c);
       query.setMaxResults(10);
        List check1 =query.list();
       java.util.Iterator on=check1.iterator();
        while(on.hasNext())
         {
        Object oo[]=(Object[])on.next();

            name=(String)oo[0].toString().trim();
            age=(String)oo[1].toString().trim();
            address=(String)oo[2].toString().trim();
            phone_no=(String)oo[3].toString().trim();


              %>
           <div align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc "> Name &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="text" value="<%=name %> " disabled="disabled">
    <br><br>

            </div>
               <%        }

                     }       
             catch(Exception ee){
            out.print(ee.getMessage());

             }
          %>

          <center>  <img src="fgfdg.png"> </center>
            <table align="center">
             <tr>
              <td><a href="Pagecount?c=0">First Page</a></td>
              <%
           int value_counter=0;
           int pagecount=0;
              long counters=0;
               try{
              org.hibernate.Query query=Listsession.createQuery("select count(*) from paging order by auto_inc"); 

            List check1 =query.list();
                java.util.Iterator on=check1.iterator();
            while(on.hasNext())
              {
              Object oo=on.next();

                counters=((Number)oo).longValue();


                    }}

             catch(Exception e)
              {
              out.println(e);
                  }  

              int count=(int)counters/10; 
              int Counter_in_int=count*10;
             double xyz=Counter_in_int-counters;
               if(xyz>=0)
               {
               for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
              {

                   pagecount++; 
                %>  
             <td><a href="Pagecount?c=<%=value_counter %>"><%= pagecount%></a></td> 
             <% value_counter=value_counter+10;} }
             else
              {
                   %>

             <%
                for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
                 {
                  pagecount++; 
               %> 
                 <td><a href="Pagecount?c=<%=value_counter %>"><%= pagecount%></a></td>          
               <% value_counter=value_counter+10;} }
                  %>
           <td><a href="Pagecount?c=<%=value_counter-10 %>">Last Page</a></td>
            </tr>
           </table>

        </body>
           </html>
```

This is corresponding servlet

```
package testingpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/nn"})
public class Pagecount extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            request.setAttribute("c", request.getParameter("c"));
            RequestDispatcher rd=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/pager.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

}
```

And the database contains 30 records:

```
Name

Tom
Mary
Martha
Angelina
Joe
Gordon
Kim
Steve
Kristen
John
Mike
Smith
Daniel
Sheamus
Vince
Longbottom
Harry
Hermione
Ron
Peter
Sammy
Fitzgerald
Leonardo
Ben
Bruce
Jude
Richie
Kate
William
Ron
```

After running this page i get 10 results on each page.I know that while inserting data in MySQL we insert it on 1st position(indexing in MYSQL starts from 1) but while retrieving data the data on 1st index of MYSQl comes on index 0 in our list.

So My question is-
How could the above code working correctly because on 1st page it is printing names from
"Tom" to "John" i.e. first 10 records from database but now when i click on 2nd page and the c is set to 10 now and it is again printing records from "Mike" to "Peter" but it should print from "john to Ron" because john is at 10th position in the array.

Comment: Please, don't use scriplets! Look at MVC Model 2: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/Journal200603.jsp#a5

Comment: @Anton Hey man i didn't understood the link u gave me can u tell me what i can use in the above code instead of scriplets.I was thinking ab out JSTL but without JSTL and scriplet how i would be able to write java code in a JSP page.

Comment: You got "Ron" twice in your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I can tell it is printing the expected results. The first index is 0 so the element with index 10 is the eleventh one, which correponds to "Mike".

Comment: thanks for giving me the answer can u tell me any way to manipulate a jsp page or write java code in a jsp page except JSTL and scriplets.